# Is there a way to get all User Claims using Asp.Net Core 2.2?

Tags: asp.net-core-2.2

I'm migrating my application from Asp.Net MVC 5 to Asp.Net Core 2.2. How do I get the logged in User Claims in Asp.Net Core 2.2?

Asp.Net MVC 5 code:

```
var identity = new ClaimsPrincipal(User).Claims; //returns 141 claims
```

Asp.Net Core 2.2 code:

```
var identity = User.Claims.ToArray(); //returns 75 claims for same user id
```

I expect Asp.Net Core 2.2 application to return 141 claims but the actual claims returned are 75.

----------------Startup.cs File-----------------

```
public class Startup
{
    public Startup(IConfiguration configuration)
    {
        Configuration = configuration;
    }

    public IConfiguration Configuration { get; }

    // This method gets called by the runtime. Use this method to add services to the container.
    public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
    {
        //CSRF
        services.AddAntiforgery(options => options.HeaderName = "X-XSRF-TOKEN");

        //Below methods are default methods that came with Core template.
        services.AddMvc().SetCompatibilityVersion(CompatibilityVersion.Version_2_2);

        // In production, the Angular files will be served from this directory
        services.AddSpaStaticFiles(configuration =>
        {
            configuration.RootPath = "ClientApp/dist";
        });
    }

    // This method gets called by the runtime. Use this method to configure the HTTP request pipeline.
    public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IHostingEnvironment env, IAntiforgery antiforgery)
    {
        if (env.IsDevelopment())
        {
            app.UseDeveloperExceptionPage();
        }
        else
        {
            app.UseExceptionHandler("/Error");
            // The default HSTS value is 30 days. You may want to change this for production scenarios, see https://aka.ms/aspnetcore-hsts.
            app.UseHsts();
        }

        app.UseHttpsRedirection();

        app.Use(async (context, next) =>
        {
            string path = context.Request.Path.Value;
            if (path != null && !path.ToLower().Contains("/api"))
            {
                // XSRF-TOKEN used by angular in the $http if provided
                var tokens = antiforgery.GetAndStoreTokens(context);
                context.Response.Cookies.Append("XSRF-TOKEN",
                  tokens.RequestToken, new CookieOptions
                  {
                      HttpOnly = false,
                      Secure = true
                  }
                );
            }
            await next();
        });


        app.UseSpaStaticFiles();

        app.UseMvc(routes =>
        {
            routes.MapRoute(
                name: "default",
                template: "{controller}/{action=Index}/{id?}");
        });

        app.UseSpa(spa =>
        {
            // To learn more about options for serving an Angular SPA from ASP.NET Core,
            // see https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?linkid=864501

            spa.Options.SourcePath = "ClientApp";

            if (env.IsDevelopment())
            {
                spa.Options.StartupTimeout = new System.TimeSpan(0, 0, 160);
                spa.UseAngularCliServer(npmScript: "start");
            }
        });
    }
}
```

Comment: Without seeing your code it's hard to say, but my guess is that some claims are filtered. You can try by adding this line `JwtSecurityTokenHandler.DefaultInboundClaimTypeMap.Clear();` to your startup. Otherwise investigate what claim types are missing.

Comment: Sorry that line didn't help. I created a brand new asp.net core 2.2 application with Angular template and the above 2 lines are the only main code lines that's in that application. Thank you!

Comment: Those lines are not relevant, can you show the startup? And did you investigate what claim types are missing?

Comment: Added my Startup.cs file.